# Can I use Dominated Convergence Theorem for this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} (sz)^n\right]e^{-s}$$

Does this product decay to zero, as $s$ goes to infinity?

Assume the left-hand term, call it $\phi(sz)$, is entire.

Also, you can assume that we have this upper bound $|\phi(sz)|< Me^{|sz|}$

Then, using the upper bound, the product converges to zero easily, for $|z|<1$.  I want to show that it also converges to zero on the boundary, $|z|=1$.

EDIT:  Is this argument valid?

The series, phi, converges uniformly, by the Weierstrass M-test.  Or, a weaker statement that doesn't use the uniform convergence:  phi is bounded by something that is summable, namely the exponential series.  In both cases, we may then take the limit, as s goes to infinity, inside of the summation.  Think of the Dominated Convergence Theorem for integration.  Then we have, for sums, $lim_{n->\infty}(lim_{s->\infty} S_n) * lim_{s->\infty} (e^{-s})$.  Then this evaluates to zero.

Comment: Take the example $a_n = 1$ then $\phi(sz) = e^{sz}$ so if $z=1$ we have $\phi(sz)e^{-s} = 1$ which does not go to zero.

Comment: I agree, @Winther ... something is wrong with my work, just can't seem to catch the error...

Comment: What error? If you have a faulty proof of this then post it and I'm sure someone will spot the error in the argument. btw the statement is correct for $|z|<1$ it's just not enough to be able to establish it on $|z|=1$.

Comment: Hi @Winther, what do you think of this argument?  The series, phi, converges uniformly, by the Weierstrass M-test.  Or, a weaker statement that doesn't use the uniform convergence:  phi is bounded by something that is summable, namely the exponential series.  In both cases, we may then take the limit, as s goes to infinity, inside of the summation.  Think of the Dominated Convergence Theorem for integration.  Then we have, for sums, $lim_{n->\infty}(lim_{s->\infty} S_n) * lim_{s->\infty} (e^{-s})$.  Then this evaluates to zero.

Comment: -- I've also put this comment up on my question post, too.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think the upper bound makes it work, @Winter, but I am not 100% convinced ...

Comment: Just to be clear: the result cannot hold as my counter-example above shows. The fault in the argument above is $\lim_{s\to\infty}\phi(sz)e^{-s}  = \lim_{s\to\infty}\phi(sz)\lim_{s\to\infty}e^{-s}$. Only when you know that both limits are finite is this allowed and this is not the case here.

Comment: I agree again with you @Winther.  The result only holds on |z|<1.  There must be a mistake in the question, I think.  Thanks for your time.